# Responsive image that fit to div

Tags: image, css

How can I do similar responsive images? Like on this page.

http://pixelgrade.com/demos/border/

I was trying do this with css, but with no effects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-size:cover` property

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
.responsive_bg{
  background:url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/ShiFengWaterFall_002.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yirisizo/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

This image is set as a background-image. Do you have any code to share with us so we might help?

Basically, instead of writing the usual image:

```
<img src="this/cool/image.png" />
```

you would use a regular div that you size according to the responsive behavior you want to see:

```
<div style="background-image: url(this/cool/image.png)"></div>
```

and the CSS that comes with to style the image (background) itself:

```
div{
    background-size:cover; // fills the div
    background-position; 50% 50%; //centers the background
    //add here some way to get your div to be the proper size for responsiveness
}
```

And of course, you use media-queries to add some more responsiveness to the whole shenanigan.